# Déjà Dup “Revert to Previous Version” is missing from Nautilus's file context menu

Tags: nautilus, menu, restore, deja-dup

I used to browse to a file in Nautilus, right click it and select
“Revert to Previous Version” (or something close) to replace it with a backed-up copy. The Nautilus context menu option is missing now.

I uninstalled and re-installed Déjà Dup. No help. The full restore option  from the Deja Dup program still works, but I can no longer restore individual files. It is like the integration between Nautilus and Deja Dup was lost.

I'm running Ubuntu 18.08 and Déjà Dup v40.7.
This is a similar question to "Nautilus + Deja Dup: no menu item for “File -> Restore Missing Files…”, 3+ years ago, but it was never resolved.

I would appreciate any help. I used the restore option frequently to get back to a known good file.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this integration has been dropped as DejaDup now includes its own built-in browser https://bugs.launchpad.net/deja-dup-caja/+bug/1885063

Comment: Your correct. I read what the maintainer of deja-dup wrote: "I've also dropped the nautilus plugin entirely...and the restore-missing functionality..."  That's a shame. The easy file restore feature was the primary reason that I used deja-dup.